# A simplified expression for $\left(\sum_idx_i\otimes f_i\right)^k$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle over a smooth manifold. Let $\eta=\sum_idx_i\otimes f_i\in\Omega^1(X,End(E))$ be an end-valued 1-form on $M$. Is there a simplified expression for
$$\eta^k=\left(\sum_idx_i\otimes f_i\right)^k?$$
In other words I am looking for  endomorphisms $g_I$ such that
$$\eta^k=\sum_Idx_I\otimes g_I$$
with $I=\{i_1<...<i_k\}$.

Comment: @Physor Sections of $\Lambda^1(TX) \otimes \mathrm{End}(E)$, which is a vector bundle over $X$.

Comment: @Physor $f_i$ and $g_I$ are therefore sections of $End(E)$.

Comment: Sorry I don't know these things very much yet,

Comment: So by $k$th power you don't mean the $k$th tensor power? You mean the $k$th exterior power with tensor power of $\text{End}(E)$ contracting to give composition? The notation is somewhat ill-defined, to mathematicians, at any rate.